# Unable to save page and block changes using Page Builder with enabled js minification

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

Anyone facing this issue with Magento 2.3.3 EE?

Unable to save page and block changes using Page Builder with enabled js minification.

Magento Version: 2.3.3 EE

Steps to reproduce:

- Stores->Settings->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->JavaScript Settings->Minify JavaScript Files = Yes
- Set production bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
- Go to Content->Elements->Blocks\Pages->Edit
- Make changes and Save
- Changes are not saved

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I used the solution shared here https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/magento/magento2/25620/565720155 and it fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and just FYI, this issue was fixed in Magento version 2.3.4. If you haven't already upgraded your Magento instance to something much newer (as of this time 2.4.1 is the latest version available), I would recommend upgrading to 2.3.4 to resolve this issue.

Here is the documentation on upgrading: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Alternatively, Magento did release a patch to resolve this issue if for some reason you cannot/do not want to upgrade your Magento version, which you can by submitting a ticket through Magento support.